# Model-View-Presentor Clarification Needed

Tags: oop, user-interface, design-patterns, mvp

I need some guidance with the interaction of different components in MVP.

For example, I have an application to manage data in a hospital. So let's assume the UI has a patient editor. Now as far as I understand MVP, I would create a `PatientPresenter` with a `PatientView` and a `PatientModel`. Now the `PatientView` would show the user interface and when it changes delegate it to `PatientPresenter` which would then update `PatientModel`. When the model changes, should it inform the presenter or directly inform the view which then updates the view?

Now let us assume there's a parent component, a `PatientManager` which shows an overview of patients, allows to search the patients and so on. Now I could do another triad for this component, but how would it interact with the `PatientModel/View/Presenter`?

It would make sense to me if the `PatientManagerMode` would have several `PatientModel`s and it would also make sense to me if the `PatientManagerView` holds an instance of the `PatientView` as a childcontrol, however why should the `PatientManagerPresenter` hold an instance of the `PatientPresenter`? And if it shouldn't, who should?

So what exactly should happen if I double click something in the `PatientManager` so that I can edit the patient?

Answer (score 0):

> When the model changes, should it
>   inform the presenter or directly
>   inform the view which then updates the
>   view?

The model should inform the presenter which then updates the view.

> Now let us assume there's a parent
>   component, a PatientManager which
>   shows an overview of patients, ... but
>   how would it interact with the
>   PatientModel/View/Presenter?

I would consider them as subviews of a larger UI that deals with managing Patients. In this case the Presenter would handle both. Taking responsibility for filling out the Patient Manager and responding to searches. Then when the operator selects a patient the view passes that to the presents. Then when the patient details are brought out the presents retrieves the data from the model and fill out the patient details.

The way I would layer it is like this

View Assembly/EXE/Package
Presenter Assembly/DLL/Package
Commands Assembly/DLL/Package
Presenter Manager Assembly/DLL/Package
Model  Assembly/DLL/Package

The View would implement the view interfaces found in the Presenter say IPatientManagerView and IPatientView and registers themselves with the Presenter. The implementations would use the Presenter Interfaces exposed through Presenter Manager. For example IPatientManager and IPatient

The Presenters would implement the Presenter Interface found in the Presenter Manager and register themselves in the Presenter Manager. It could be one class that implements both IPatientManager and IPatient or two. When it needs to perform an action either UI related or Model related it executes a command found in Commands. The command would use the Model and/or the Presenter Interfaces to perform the action.

To bring up a patient would look something like this.

You have a dialog that implements IPatientManagerView and is registered with a class that implements IPatientManager.

- User clicks Search
- Search calls the Search Method of
  IPatientManager
- The class implement IPatientManager
  uses IPatientManagerView to retrieves
  the search parameters.
- Then setups up and execute the Search
  Command which retrieves a list of
  patient.
- The Search Command calls ListPatients
  on IPatientManager
- The class implementing
  IPatientManager uses a method
  IPatientManagerView to clear and fill
  out the list of patient.

---

- User Double Clicks on a Patient
- The Dialog implement
  IPatientManagerView will call the
  class implementing IPatientManager
  indicating that a specific patient is
  to be view.
- The class implementing
  IPatientManager retrieves the
  information about the patient needed
  to view from the dialog implementing
  IPatientManageView
- IPatientManager then setups and
  executes a command to view the
  Patient.
- The command retrieves all the
  patient's information from the Model
  and calls the ViewPatient Method on
  the class implementing
  IPatientManager
- IPatientManager then retrieves the
  class implementing IPatient.
- Passes the patient information to
  IPatients and tells it to display
  itself. IPatient then retrieves the
  IPatientView that is registered with
  it.
- Fill it out with with the patient
  data using IPatientView and then
  tells IPatientView to display itself.

With this scheme you can radically change the UI by changing what implements the various view interfaces. You can also easily right automated test by creating dummy classes that implement the View interfaces. Plus for future maintenance every interaction is explicitly documented through the interfaces.